# Produce decision version of the problem

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, reductions

An optimisation problem requires minimising some function $f(x)$, where $x$ is a
vector of integers. What is the corresponding decision version of the problem?

Comment: what are the steps of creating decision versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Given $f(x)$, what is $\min(f(x))$?" becomes "Given $f(x)$, and $k$, decide if there is an $x$ such that $f(x)< k$?"

Comment: I see from the edit @blk that a decision must be a yes or no answer question?

Comment: Indeed. Your question is very basic. Please consult some introductory books on computability or complexity theory.